# Changing FTP Permissions for User

Tags: linux

I am new at Linux administration.  I created a new SSH user and password, and edited iptables to allow FTP access to my server.  I am able to login with my user via FTP, however, when I try to upload files or create directories, I get "550 Permission Denied" errors.  I am sure that it is similar a matter of permissions for my user account, but since I am new, I have no idea how to configure the permissions.  Is there a certain config file that I need to edit?

Comment: You should add what FTP server package you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out on my own.  The problem was that I needed to add write_enable=YES to the vsftpd.conf file.

Comment: You can check your own answer as "accepted", so other people looking for this same issue would benefit from your answer.